# Debug a python script called from C#

Tags: c#, python

I run python scripts from C# with the following code:

```
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = Path.Combine("myPath", "python.exe");
        startInfo.Arguments = "-u ";
        startInfo.Arguments += "MyScript.py" + applicationSpecificArguments;
        using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
        {
            process.WaitForExit();
        }
```

Question: How can I debug the python script "MyScript.py" in VisualStudio 2017? I cannot directly run and debug the script because of application specific arguments, which can only be calculated by the C#-Part.

My solution contains a python project containing "MyScript.py" and the calling C# Code.
When I set a break point in "MyScript.py" and start the C#-application, the breakpoint gets disabled.
I also tried to attach the debugger to the process which is created by Process.Start(), but the same happened: Breakpoint was disabled.

Comment: You need to use the [python debugging tools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Comment: Maybe this also applies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017

Comment: @Fildor Does the pdb work with Visual studio or is it standalone? The microsoft link you posted applies to running python from Visual Studio but not debugging python code that is executed in a separate process.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint in your C# code (using Visual Studio) just after `startInfo.Arguments += "MyScript.py" + applicationSpecificArguments;` and copy the arguments. Then, you can debug your python script (e.g. by running the script from PyCharm) with the arguments that you have just copied.

Comment: Probably not a solution for you; but maybe https://ironpython.net/ is something you could use

Comment: @Timmeh: ironpython would be very cool if it would support python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

The comment from @Infected brought me to the following solution: 
The arguments being passed to the script are stored in the node "CommandLineArguments" of the python project file. So, when debugging,

- modify the existing python project file
- start a new instance of Visual Studio instead of python.exe

In the new Visual Studio Window I can start debugging as usual.

Code looks like this:

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe";
                string pyProjectFile = @"D:\myPythonProject.pyproj";
                string pyProjectFileTemp =  @"D:\myPythonProjectTemp.pyproj";
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(pyProjectFile);
                XmlNodeList myNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("CommandLineArguments");
                myNodes[0].FirstChild.Value = applicationSpecificArguments;
                doc.Save(pyProjectFileTemp);
                //Pass the modified project file as argument to Visual Studio
                startInfo.Arguments += pyProjectFileTemp;
            }
```

Thanks to @Infected and the other contributors!